# Excel find number from within date range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am sure i am being stupid here but i cannot see an easy solution for what should be a simple query. I have a range of values against a date such as;

[Excel Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsRiH.png)

All i need to do is calculate the value for a different date, say Oct 31. I can easily create a slope and offset or a graph with a linear trendline but eveytime i use these Excel returns the incorrect result. I dont doubt it is linked to dates rather than numbers as i can easily replicate with numbers.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to **interpolate** without having to draw a graph ??

Comment: Indeed, although i dont mind drawing a graph if needs be. I can easily create a slope and intercept, what i am missing is how to apply these when my y axis is dd-mm-yy and my x axis a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, in Excel, dates are just numbers in sheep's clothing *(formatted as dates)*  Your data:

[image]

Is not perfectly linear, but we can still use a linear fit:

[image]

In **C1** put the slope formula:

```
=SLOPE(B1:B5,A1:A5)
```

In **C2** put the intercept formula:

```
=INTERCEPT(B1:B5,A1:A5)
```

In **D1** put the desired *X*:

31 October 2019

Finally in **E1** put the formula for the estimated *Y*:

```
=$C$1*D1+$C$2
```

[image]

*(Note we did **not** use the graph anywhere to get the numerical result)*

Comment: That is pretty much exactly as i did, what i didnt realise is the returned value needed to be formatted, as soon as i set the formatting as number it worked!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me

Comment: @DavidMackay You are quite welcome!